# ShapeRenderer doesn't render in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am developing a 2D 8 pool game using LibGDX,I am a newbie so I don't know how to solve this , I used ShapeRenderer of type line to draw a line between the white ball and the mouse pointer if mouse is pressed,but for some reason it doesn't work. 
In Render()

```
if(cueball.CheckBallMovement()) {//if cueball stopped moving
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
                Vector3 vv=new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);//translate mouse coordinates world coordinates
                camera.unproject(vv);
                sr.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
                sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
                sr.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
                sr.line(cueball.Ball.getWorldCenter().x, cueball.Ball.getWorldCenter().y,
                        vv.x,vv.y);
                sr.end();
                System.out.println("ss");`
```

It prints out the "ss" but doesn't render the line.I don't know if this helps, but here are my camera ratios In create()

```
world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),true); // x= 0 and y =0 means no gravity
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    camera =new OrthographicCamera(VirtualWidth/20,VirtualHeight/20);
```